# how to send back to the command line, when command line vi mode opens an external editor?

Tags: vim, command-line, vi

When using command line vim mode (set -o vi) and I type 'v', it takes me to an external editor. How do I send back the edited command back to the command line

Comment: _set -o vi_ is the greatest thing in the world!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just quit the editor.  :wq works as does ZZ as mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Using "ZZ" works for me.

In other words: Shift-Z + Shift-Z